# MPAndroidChart LineChart Showing just on LineData

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am having problem creating LineChart it's just showing the last Line when I need to show all Lines can you please help? here's the code:

```
Collections.addAll(labels,` column);
dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
for (monthlysales company : companieslist) {
entries.clear();
for (int j = 0; j < listofcompanies.Total.size(); j++) {
entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(listofcompanies.Total.get(j)), j));
}
setComp1 = new LineDataSet(entries, company.StoreName);
setComp1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
setComp1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
dataSets.add(setComp1);
}
LineData data = new LineData(column,dataSets);
linechart.setData(data);
linechart.setDescription("Sales");
linechart.animateXY(5000,5000);
linechart.setPinchZoom(true);
linechart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(true);
linechart.setDragDecelerationEnabled(true);
linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
linechart.invalidate();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's now solved by creating a Function and call it as below :

```
 **dataSets.add(createLineChart(company,company.StoreName,company.Total));**

                data = new LineData(column,dataSets);


                linechart.setData(data);
                linechart.invalidate();
                linechart.setDescription("Sales");
```

and this is the function:

```
 private LineDataSet createLineChart(monthlysales company,String storeName,List<String> listofcompanies){
  //  LineData data=new LineData();
    ArrayList<Entry> entries= new ArrayList<Entry>();
    for (int j = 0; j < listofcompanies.size(); j++) {

        entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(listofcompanies.get(j)),j));

linechart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    Random rd = new Random();
    setComp1 = new LineDataSet(entries,storeName);


    setComp1.setColor(Color.argb(255,rd.nextInt(256),rd.nextInt(256),rd.nextInt(256)));


   // LineData data =new LineData(labels,dataset);
    return setComp1;

}
```

it seems that the LineDataSet was used the last time it was called displaying just one line.

Answer (score 1):

This actually makes sense. You are adding data to the `entries` list, and then add it to the DataSet correctly. The problem is, you are clearing the entries list every time after you add it. you should use a separate list for each dataset.

replace the line:

```
entries.clear();
```

with

```
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I replaced it but it didnt work, which is weird, when debugging, the  data in linechart.setData(data); I see that it has all 4 mDataSets which each  contains a list of mYVals that contains all the data . Is there any boolean or something that must be toggled to display all the lines?Thank you

Comment: No there is no boolean to do that. Can you please try to intialize setComp1 every time in a separate object too? I mean use `LineDataSet setComp1 = new LineDataSet(entries, company.StoreName);` instead of `setComp1 = new LineDataSet(entries, company.StoreName);`

Comment: use this with the `List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();` that I mentioned in the answer

Comment: Your using the library the correct way. but I guess there's something wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Same issue, it didn't work, it works if I create a new dataSet let's say called SetComp2 and add it to dataSets... don't know how to solve it this way.